# Try to run resource and got " '}' expected (to close '{' at line 5) near "

Tags: lua, resources, fivem

Tried to run a FXManifest for my Resource and got

> " Error: CAK-Sounds failed to load: Could not parse resource metadata
> file
> D:/txData/ESXLegacy_99D8F7.base/resources//[carsounds]/CAK-Sounds/fxmanifest.lua:
> CAK-Sounds/fxmanifest.lua:85: '}' expected (to close '{' at line 5)
> near ''audioconfig/488sound_game.dat151.rel''"

My Manifest looks like this

````
fx_version 'adamant'

game 'gta5'

files {
  'audioconfig/lambov10_game.dat151.rel',
  'audioconfig/lambov10_sounds.dat54.rel',
  'sfx/dlc_lambov10/lambov10.awc',
  'sfx/dlc_lambov10/lambov10_npc.awc',
  'audioconfig/musv8_game.dat151.rel',
  'audioconfig/musv8_sounds.dat54.rel',
  'sfx/dlc_musv8/musv8.awc',
  'sfx/dlc_musv8/musv8_npc.awc',
  'audioconfig/brabus850_game.dat151.rel',
  'audioconfig/brabus850_sounds.dat54.rel',
  'sfx/dlc_brabus850/brabus850.awc',
  'sfx/dlc_brabus850/brabus850_npc.awc',
  'audioconfig/shonen_game.dat151.rel',
  'audioconfig/shonen_sounds.dat54.rel',
  'sfx/dlc_shonen/shonen.awc',
  'sfx/dlc_shonen/shonen_npc.awc',
  'audioconfig/toysupmk4_game.dat151.nametable',
  'audioconfig/toysupmk4_game.dat151.rel',
  'audioconfig/toysupmk4_sounds.dat54.nametable',
  'audioconfig/toysupmk4_sounds.dat54.rel',
  'sfx/dlc_toysupmk4/toysupmk4.awc',
  'sfx/dlc_toysupmk4/toysupmk4_npc.awc',
  'audioconfig/rb26dett_amp.dat10.rel',
  'audioconfig/rb26dett_game.dat151.rel',
  'audioconfig/rb26dett_sounds.dat54.rel',
  'sfx/dlc_rb26dett/rb26dett.awc',
  'sfx/dlc_rb26dett/rb26dett_npc.awc',
  'audioconfig/rotary7_game.dat151.rel',
  'audioconfig/rotary7_sounds.dat54.rel',
  'sfx/dlc_rotary7/rotary7.awc',
  'sfx/dlc_rotary7/rotary7_npc.awc',
  'audioconfig/m297zonda_amp.dat10.nametable',
  'audioconfig/m297zonda_amp.dat10.rel',
  'audioconfig/m297zonda_game.dat151.nametable',
  'audioconfig/m297zonda_game.dat151.rel',
  'audioconfig/m297zonda_sounds.dat54.nametable',
  'audioconfig/m297zonda_sounds.dat54.rel',
  'sfx/dlc_m297zonda/m297zonda.awc',
  'sfx/dlc_m297zonda/m297zonda_npc.awc',
  'audioconfig/m158huayra_amp.dat10.nametable',
  'audioconfig/m158huayra_amp.dat10.rel',
  'audioconfig/m158huayra_game.dat151.nametable',
  'audioconfig/m158huayra_game.dat151.rel',
  'audioconfig/m158huayra_sounds.dat54.nametable',
  'audioconfig/m158huayra_sounds.dat54.rel',
  'sfx/dlc_m158huayra/m158huayra.awc',
  'sfx/dlc_m158huayra/m158huayra_npc.awc',
  'audioconfig/k20a_amp.dat10.nametable',
  'audioconfig/k20a_amp.dat10.rel',
  'audioconfig/k20a_game.dat151.nametable',
  'audioconfig/k20a_game.dat151.rel',
  'audioconfig/k20a_sounds.dat54.nametable',
  'audioconfig/k20a_sounds.dat54.rel',
  'sfx/dlc_k20a/k20a.awc',
  'sfx/dlc_k20a/k20a_npc.awc',
  'audioconfig/gt3flat6_amp.dat10.nametable',
  'audioconfig/gt3flat6_amp.dat10.rel',
  'audioconfig/gt3flat6_game.dat151.nametable',
  'audioconfig/gt3flat6_game.dat151.rel',
  'audioconfig/gt3flat6_sounds.dat54.nametable',
  'audioconfig/gt3flat6_sounds.dat54.rel',
  'sfx/dlc_gt3flat6/gt3flat6.awc',
  'sfx/dlc_gt3flat6/gt3flat6_npc.awc',
  'audioconfig/predatorv8_amp.dat10.nametable',
  'audioconfig/predatorv8_amp.dat10.rel',
  'audioconfig/predatorv8_game.dat151.nametable',
  'audioconfig/predatorv8_game.dat151.rel',
  'audioconfig/predatorv8_sounds.dat54.nametable',
  'audioconfig/predatorv8_sounds.dat54.rel',
  'sfx/dlc_predatorv8/predatorv8.awc',
  'sfx/dlc_predatorv8/predatorv8_npc.awc',
  'audioconfig/p60b40_amp.dat10.nametable',
  'audioconfig/p60b40_amp.dat10.rel',
  'audioconfig/p60b40_game.dat151.nametable',
  'audioconfig/p60b40_game.dat151.rel',
  'audioconfig/p60b40_sounds.dat54.nametable',
  'audioconfig/p60b40_sounds.dat54.rel',
  'sfx/dlc_p60b40/p60b40.awc',
  'sfx/dlc_p60b40/p60b40_npc.awc'
  'audioconfig/488sound_game.dat151.rel',
  'audioconfig/488sound_sounds.dat54.rel',
  'sfx/dlc_488sound/488sound.awc',
  'sfx/dlc_488sound/488sound_npc.awc',
  'audioconfig/apollosv8_game.dat151.rel',
  'audioconfig/apollosv8_sounds.dat54.rel',
  'sfx/dlc_apollosv8/apollosv8.awc',
  'sfx/dlc_apollosv8/apollosv8_npc.awc',
  'audioconfig/c6v8sound_game.dat151.rel',
  'audioconfig/c6v8sound_sounds.dat54.rel',
  'sfx/dlc_c6v8sound/c6v8sound.awc',
  'sfx/dlc_c6v8sound/c6v8sound_npc.awc',
  'audioconfig/diablov12_game.dat151.rel',
  'audioconfig/diablov12_sounds.dat54.rel',
  'sfx/dlc_diablov12/diablov12.awc',
  'sfx/dlc_diablov12/diablov12_npc.awc',
  'audioconfig/f40v8_game.dat151.rel',
  'audioconfig/f40v8_sounds.dat54.rel',
  'sfx/dlc_f40v8/f40v8.awc',
  'sfx/dlc_f40v8/f40v8_npc.awc',
  'audioconfig/f50v12_game.dat151.rel',
  'audioconfig/f50v12_sounds.dat54.rel',
  'sfx/dlc_f50v12/f50v12.awc',
  'sfx/dlc_f50v12/f50v12_npc.awc',
  'audioconfig/ferrarif12_game.dat151.rel',
  'audioconfig/ferrarif12_sounds.dat54.rel',
  'sfx/dlc_ferrarif12/ferrarif12.awc',
  'sfx/dlc_ferrarif12/ferrarif12_npc.awc',
  'audioconfig/sestov10_game.dat151.rel',
  'audioconfig/sestov10_sounds.dat54.rel',
  'sfx/dlc_sestov10/sestov10.awc',
  'sfx/dlc_sestov10/sestov10_npc.awc',
  'audioconfig/urusv8_game.dat151.rel',
  'audioconfig/urusv8_sounds.dat54.rel',
  'sfx/dlc_urusv8/urusv8.awc',
  'sfx/dlc_urusv8/urusv8_npc.awc',
  'audioconfig/viperv10_game.dat151.rel',
  'audioconfig/viperv10_sounds.dat54.rel',
  'sfx/dlc_viperv10/viperv10.awc',
  'sfx/dlc_viperv10/viperv10_npc.awc',
  'audioconfig/gtaspanov10_game.dat151.rel',
  'audioconfig/gtaspanov10_sounds.dat54.rel',
  'sfx/dlc_gtaspanov10/gtaspanov10.awc',
  'sfx/dlc_gtaspanov10/gtaspanov10_npc.awc',
  'audioconfig/laferrarisound_game.dat151.rel',
  'audioconfig/laferrarisound_sounds.dat54.rel',
  'sfx/dlc_laferrarisound/laferrarisound.awc',
  'sfx/dlc_laferrarisound/laferrarisound_npc.awc',
  'audioconfig/mclarenv8_game.dat151.rel',
  'audioconfig/mclarenv8_sounds.dat54.rel',
  'sfx/dlc_mclarenv8/mclarenv8.awc',
  'sfx/dlc_mclarenv8/mclarenv8_npc.awc',
  'audioconfig/murciev12_game.dat151.rel',
  'audioconfig/murciev12_sounds.dat54.rel',
  'sfx/dlc_murciev12/murciev12.awc',
  'sfx/dlc_murciev12/murciev12_npc.awc',
  'audioconfig/perfov10_game.dat151.rel',
  'audioconfig/perfov10_sounds.dat54.rel',
  'sfx/dlc_perfov10/perfov10.awc',
  'sfx/dlc_perfov10/perfov10_npc.awc',
  'audioconfig/veyronsound_game.dat151.rel',
  'audioconfig/veyronsound_sounds.dat54.rel',
  'sfx/dlc_veyronsound/veyronsound.awc',
  'sfx/dlc_veyronsound/veyronsound_npc.awc'
  'audioconfig/*.dat151.rel',
  'audioconfig/*.dat54.rel',
  'sfx/**/*.awc'
}

data_file 'AUDIO_GAMEDATA' 'audioconfig/lambov10_game.dat'
data_file 'AUDIO_SOUNDDATA' 'audioconfig/lambov10_sounds.dat'
data_file 'AUDIO_WAVEPACK' 'sfx/dlc_lambov10'
data_file 'AUDIO_GAMEDATA' 'audioconfig/musv8_game.dat'
data_file 'AUDIO_SOUNDDATA' 'audioconfig/musv8_sounds.dat'
data_file 'AUDIO_WAVEPACK' 'sfx/dlc_musv8'
data_file 'AUDIO_GAMEDATA' 'audioconfig/brabus850_game.dat'
data_file 'AUDIO_SOUNDDATA' 'audioconfig/brabus850_sounds.dat'
data_file 'AUDIO_WAVEPACK' 'sfx/dlc_brabus850'
data_file 'AUDIO_GAMEDATA' 'audioconfig/shonen_game.dat'
data_file 'AUDIO_SOUNDDATA' 'audioconfig/shonen_sounds.dat'
data_file 'AUDIO_WAVEPACK' 'sfx/dlc_shonen'
data_file 'AUDIO_GAMEDATA' 'audioconfig/toysupmk4_game.dat'
data_file 'AUDIO_SOUNDDATA' 'audioconfig/toysupmk4_sounds.dat'
data_file 'AUDIO_WAVEPACK' 'sfx/dlc_toysupmk4'
data_file 'AUDIO_SYNTHDATA' 'audioconfig/rb26dett_amp.dat'
data_file 'AUDIO_GAMEDATA' 'audioconfig/rb26dett_game.dat'
data_file 'AUDIO_SOUNDDATA' 'audioconfig/rb26dett_sounds.dat'
data_file 'AUDIO_WAVEPACK' 'sfx/dlc_rb26dett'
data_file 'AUDIO_GAMEDATA' 'audioconfig/rotary7_game.dat'
data_file 'AUDIO_SOUNDDATA' 'audioconfig/rotary7_sounds.dat'
data_file 'AUDIO_WAVEPACK' 'sfx/dlc_rotary7'
data_file 'AUDIO_SYNTHDATA' 'audioconfig/m297zonda_amp.dat'
data_file 'AUDIO_GAMEDATA' 'audioconfig/m297zonda_game.dat'
data_file 'AUDIO_SOUNDDATA' 'audioconfig/m297zonda_sounds.dat'
data_file 'AUDIO_WAVEPACK' 'sfx/dlc_m297zonda'
data_file 'AUDIO_SYNTHDATA' 'audioconfig/m158huayra_amp.dat'
data_file 'AUDIO_GAMEDATA' 'audioconfig/m158huayra_game.dat'
data_file 'AUDIO_SOUNDDATA' 'audioconfig/m158huayra_sounds.dat'
data_file 'AUDIO_WAVEPACK' 'sfx/dlc_m158huayra'
data_file 'AUDIO_SYNTHDATA' 'audioconfig/k20a_amp.dat'
data_file 'AUDIO_GAMEDATA' 'audioconfig/k20a_game.dat'
data_file 'AUDIO_SOUNDDATA' 'audioconfig/k20a_sounds.dat'
data_file 'AUDIO_WAVEPACK' 'sfx/dlc_k20a'
data_file 'AUDIO_SYNTHDATA' 'audioconfig/gt3flat6_amp.dat'
data_file 'AUDIO_GAMEDATA' 'audioconfig/gt3flat6_game.dat'
data_file 'AUDIO_SOUNDDATA' 'audioconfig/gt3flat6_sounds.dat'
data_file 'AUDIO_WAVEPACK' 'sfx/dlc_gt3flat6'
data_file 'AUDIO_SYNTHDATA' 'audioconfig/predatorv8_amp.dat'
data_file 'AUDIO_GAMEDATA' 'audioconfig/predatorv8_game.dat'
data_file 'AUDIO_SOUNDDATA' 'audioconfig/predatorv8_sounds.dat'
data_file 'AUDIO_WAVEPACK' 'sfx/dlc_predatorv8'
data_file 'AUDIO_SYNTHDATA' 'audioconfig/p60b40_amp.dat'
data_file 'AUDIO_GAMEDATA' 'audioconfig/p60b40_game.dat'
data_file 'AUDIO_SOUNDDATA' 'audioconfig/p60b40_sounds.dat'
data_file 'AUDIO_WAVEPACK' 'sfx/dlc_p60b40'
data_file 'AUDIO_GAMEDATA' 'audioconfig/apollosv8_game.dat'
data_file 'AUDIO_SOUNDDATA' 'audioconfig/apollosv8_sounds.dat'
data_file 'AUDIO_WAVEPACK' 'sfx/dlc_apollosv8'
data_file 'AUDIO_GAMEDATA' 'audioconfig/c6v8sound_game.dat'
data_file 'AUDIO_SOUNDDATA' 'audioconfig/c6v8sound_sounds.dat'
data_file 'AUDIO_WAVEPACK' 'sfx/dlc_c6v8sound'
data_file 'AUDIO_GAMEDATA' 'audioconfig/diablov12_game.dat'
data_file 'AUDIO_SOUNDDATA' 'audioconfig/diablov12_sounds.dat'
data_file 'AUDIO_WAVEPACK' 'sfx/dlc_diablov12'
data_file 'AUDIO_GAMEDATA' 'audioconfig/f40v8_game.dat'
data_file 'AUDIO_SOUNDDATA' 'audioconfig/f40v8_sounds.dat'
data_file 'AUDIO_WAVEPACK' 'sfx/dlc_f40v8'
data_file 'AUDIO_GAMEDATA' 'audioconfig/f50v12_game.dat'
data_file 'AUDIO_SOUNDDATA' 'audioconfig/f50v12_sounds.dat'
data_file 'AUDIO_WAVEPACK' 'sfx/dlc_f50v12'
data_file 'AUDIO_GAMEDATA' 'audioconfig/ferrarif12_game.dat'
data_file 'AUDIO_SOUNDDATA' 'audioconfig/ferrarif12_sounds.dat'
data_file 'AUDIO_WAVEPACK' 'sfx/dlc_ferrarif12'
data_file 'AUDIO_GAMEDATA' 'audioconfig/sestov10_game.dat'
data_file 'AUDIO_SOUNDDATA' 'audioconfig/sestov10_sounds.dat'
data_file 'AUDIO_WAVEPACK' 'sfx/dlc_sestov10'
data_file 'AUDIO_GAMEDATA' 'audioconfig/urusv8_game.dat'
data_file 'AUDIO_SOUNDDATA' 'audioconfig/urusv8_sounds.dat'
data_file 'AUDIO_WAVEPACK' 'sfx/dlc_urusv8'
data_file 'AUDIO_GAMEDATA' 'audioconfig/viperv10_game.dat'
data_file 'AUDIO_SOUNDDATA' 'audioconfig/viperv10_sounds.dat'
data_file 'AUDIO_WAVEPACK' 'sfx/dlc_viperv10'
data_file 'AUDIO_GAMEDATA' 'audioconfig/488sound_game.dat'
data_file 'AUDIO_SOUNDDATA' 'audioconfig/488sound_sounds.dat'
data_file 'AUDIO_WAVEPACK' 'sfx/dlc_488sound'
data_file 'AUDIO_GAMEDATA' 'audioconfig/avesvv12_game.dat'
data_file 'AUDIO_SOUNDDATA' 'audioconfig/avesvv12_sounds.dat'
data_file 'AUDIO_WAVEPACK' 'sfx/dlc_avesvv12'
data_file 'AUDIO_GAMEDATA' 'audioconfig/gtaspanov10_game.dat'
data_file 'AUDIO_SOUNDDATA' 'audioconfig/gtaspanov10_sounds.dat'
data_file 'AUDIO_WAVEPACK' 'sfx/dlc_gtaspanov10'
data_file 'AUDIO_GAMEDATA' 'audioconfig/laferrarisound_game.dat'
data_file 'AUDIO_SOUNDDATA' 'audioconfig/laferrarisound_sounds.dat'
data_file 'AUDIO_WAVEPACK' 'sfx/dlc_laferrarisound'
data_file 'AUDIO_GAMEDATA' 'audioconfig/mclarenv8_game.dat'
data_file 'AUDIO_SOUNDDATA' 'audioconfig/mclarenv8_sounds.dat'
data_file 'AUDIO_WAVEPACK' 'sfx/dlc_mclarenv8'
data_file 'AUDIO_GAMEDATA' 'audioconfig/murciev12_game.dat'
data_file 'AUDIO_SOUNDDATA' 'audioconfig/murciev12_sounds.dat'
data_file 'AUDIO_WAVEPACK' 'sfx/dlc_murciev12'
data_file 'AUDIO_GAMEDATA' 'audioconfig/perfov10_game.dat'
data_file 'AUDIO_SOUNDDATA' 'audioconfig/perfov10_sounds.dat'
data_file 'AUDIO_WAVEPACK' 'sfx/dlc_perfov10'
data_file 'AUDIO_GAMEDATA' 'audioconfig/veyronsound_game.dat'
data_file 'AUDIO_SOUNDDATA' 'audioconfig/veyronsound_sounds.dat'
data_file 'AUDIO_WAVEPACK' 'sfx/dlc_veyronsound'
data_file 'AUDIO_GAMEDATA' 'audioconfig/aq68lam52v10_game.dat'
data_file 'AUDIO_SOUNDDATA' 'audioconfig/aq68lam52v10_sounds.dat'
data_file 'AUDIO_WAVEPACK' 'sfx/dlc_aq68lam52v10'
data_file 'AUDIO_GAMEDATA' 'audioconfig/b58b30_game.dat'
data_file 'AUDIO_SOUNDDATA' 'audioconfig/b58b30_sounds.dat'
data_file 'AUDIO_WAVEPACK' 'sfx/dlc_b58b30'```


I am quite new to this so i cant do much. Tried to google itand tried to fix it myself but it didnt work. Just want to load my resource.
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

missing a comma after

```
'sfx/dlc_veyronsound/veyronsound_npc.awc'
```

it's the 4th last in that block

Comment: Oh god thank you! Because of your comment i search for commas and there is another one missing in
'sfx/dlc_p60b40/p60b40_npc.awc'